# Cassandra 3 Repair never finishes

Tags: cassandra, repair, data-scrubbing

We have a cluster with 6 nodes in datacenters (3 nodes each). We are starting a repair on one node and shortly afterwords we can find something like this in the logs:

```
ERROR [Repair#1:1] 2016-05-31 01:33:28,075 CassandraDaemon.java:195 -     Exception in thread Thread[Repair#1:1,5,RMI Runtime]
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.RepairException: [repair #e8e21070-26be-11e6-aae8-77b20cefeee5 on ..... Validation failed in /xx.xxx.xx.xx
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1525) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1511) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairJob.run(RepairJob.java:162) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
```

Afterwords nothing seems to happen anymore. We did not interrupt the repair for several days, but still nothing happens. We also tried it on two different clusters with the same result.

After searching through the web we stumbled upon https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/205256895--Validation-failed-when-running-a-nodetool-repair. It says that we should run "nodetool scrub" and if it does not help "sstablescrub".

We tried the nodetool scrub but the repair does still not work. We now started a sstablescrub but it seems to take forever. It uses only one cpu at 100% and the data and index file is growing, but it now runs for over a day and the file now only has a size of 1.2GB.

Is it normal that "sstablescrub" is so slow?

The cluster is already running for some time, and we missed the GCGraceSeconds for the repair. Might that lead to the not working repair?

We currently do not know how to get the repair running hope someone can help.

Comment: Did you identify the exact sstable file that's corrupted and causing the repair to fail?

Comment: Unfortunately we did not find the exact sstable.

Answer (score 0):

What the exception indicates is that the node was not able to receive the results from the merkle tree computation that was supposed to happen on `/xx.xxx.xx.xx`. Please check the logs for this node instead. The node you started the repair run is likely fine and does not require sstable scrubbing.

Comment: On the other node i get the message:

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot start multiple repair sessions over the same sstables

Although it is only one repair running. There is repair process started on any of the other nodes.

Comment: You could potentially be affected by [CASSANDRA-11824](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11824)